# hibernate executeUpdate wrong number of affected rows

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I'm working with Hibernate 4.1.7, and a MySQL driver. I have a very simple table, *table1*, that has 2 columns, *id* and *label*.
In this table, there are 2 lines.

My problem is: When I update the labels for all the lines, it first tells me "2 rows affected". Great. When I update the same lines with the same values, it also tells me "2 rows affected". Wrong, it should tell me "0 rows affected", as I already updated the data.

Here is the code for this:

```
public static void Integer doUpdate(){
    final Query query = hbmSesssion.createSQLQuery("UPDATE table1 SET label = 'toto'");
    final Integer result = query.executeUpdate();
    hbmSession.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

In my main:

```
System.out.println("nb updates: " + doUpdate());
//gives "nb updates: 2", that's OK
//then, I check in the Database, the update is ok, all the lines have 'toto' values
System.out.println("nb updates: " + doUpdate());
//gives "nb updates: 2", that's wrong!
```

Am I missing something essential in the docs? I have the same problem with plain JDBC statements, so I suspect a misuse of the Java/MySQL driver. Of course, if I send the same 2 queries in PhpMyAdmin, it first tells me "2 lines updated", and then "0 lines updated".

Comment: Sorry for editing my own post, but I find it strange that no one has an answer on this. Updating an SQL table through Java is a quite common task...

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but I stumbled upon this exact issue today and only found the answer after extensive Google searches.

In my situation, the JDBC connection itself has a parameter called `useAffectedRows`. Setting this parameter to true will have the JDBC driver return the affected rows instead of the found rows. My full JDBC URL looked something like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_database?useAffectedRows=true
```

To clarify on the OP's question, MySQL returns both the number of rows matched/found and the number of rows affected/changed. A row is only considered affected/changed if the UPDATE query actually causes a change to that row's data.

e.g. Here is the output when I have a table with 5 records containing `my_column` equal to 'new_value' and 5 records containing `my_column` equal to 'old_value'

```
MySQL [test_database]> update `my_table` set `my_column`= 'new_value';
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 10  Changed: 5  Warnings: 0
```

Only 5 records were actually changed by the query so the query returns 5 rows affected.

Another byproduct is that if you have an ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP timestamp column in your table, the timestamp will only be updated when the row is affected.

Comment: I should also note that this flag appears to be implementation specific. It may not exist for your particular storage engine.

Answer (score 1):

this code:

```
public static void Integer doUpdate(){
    final Query query = hbmSesssion.createSQLQuery("UPDATE table1 SET label = 'toto'");
    final Integer result = query.executeUpdate();
    hbmSession.getTransaction().commit();
```

}

Tells: you must update in table1 all rows put in label field value toto

If you want reduce the number of rows affected, you must add a `WHERE` condition.

For example you can add:

```
UPDATE table1 SET label = 'toto' where label <> 'toto'
```

With the upper query at the first UPDATE you'll have 2 rows affected and at the second 0 rows

Comment: Thanks for your time, but that's really not the question. I know what the update statement does!

Comment: @toni07: If you run on MySql those queries you'll have two times 2 rows affected

Comment: certainly not. On PhpMyAdmin I have "2 rows" and then "0 rows" as I mentionned in my post. Moreover, the same code as the Java one written in PHP (mysql_query) gives the exact result "2 rows" and then "0 rows".

Comment: On my MySql returns always 2 rows affected.

Comment: I don't know what's "your MySql", for me MySql is the system, the only thing that can give you "x rows affected" is a MySql client. Which one do you use? I guess not the very correct one, as "2 rows" is wrong, don't you agree?

Comment: @toni07: For me is correct if your code return twice "2 rows affected". The reason I try to explain in my answer. If there are other reasons to return before 2 rows and after 0 rows I hope other friends in this net can be explain.